# basic JSP, JSON, and AJAX implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I have a simple login to test `AJAX`
**Heres my snippnet:**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Test Page</title>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var action_script = $(this).closest('form1').prop('action');
    $.post(action_script, {
        userName : $(this).closest('form1').find('input[name="userName"]'),
        password : $(this).closest('form1').find('input[name="password"]')
    }, function(returned_data) {
        //this part executes once the server returns a successful response
        alert("Please fill UserName & Password!");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="LoginController" method="post">
        <!-- Login body -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="userName">Username:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**And a Controller**

```
UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO(); // instantiate database

        String userName = request.getParameter( "userName" ); // get userName String from the Login.jsp
        String password = request.getParameter( "password" ); // get password String from the Login.jsp

        if( userDAO.authenticate( userName, password ) ) // validate userName and password
        {

            UserModel userModel = userDAO.getUserDetails( userName ); // get userModel that correspond to userName parameter

            request.getSession().setAttribute( "userName", userName ); // set SESSION REQUEST to be forward to MainPage.jsp
            request.setAttribute( "userDetails", userModel ); // set REQUEST to be forward to MainPage.jsp

            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher( "MainPage.jsp" );
            rd.forward( request, response ); // forward request to MainPage.jsp
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            response.sendRedirect( "Login.jsp" );
            return;
        }
```

What i want to do is if the login failed, i want to retain the username and password to test how `AJAX` works and also if possible to test out `JSON` but i don't know yet where should i implement `JSON` to test it out.

I don't know what am i doing wrong it is my first time for web development please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you have here is what the server is returning. You want it to return a `JSON` object but it'll be returning a web page (most likely, `HTML`).

I really see one of two options here (maybe more but I can't think of them at this instant):

1. You can have a separate URL for `JSON` posts (like `action_script + ".json"`) and, within your controller, separate out the logic for validating the user credentials away from the logic that returns the result to the browser. That is, instead of one method, have three methods: (a) internal method that verifies the user credentials, (b) a public method that calls (a) and returns `HTML` or redirects, and (c) a public method that calls (a) and returns a `JSON` object.
2. Alternatively, you can detect the type of post you're receiving to look for `XHR` requests (and/or check the header of the request to look for the content-type of "application/json") and output the `JSON` object in those circumstances.

The implementation is really up to you and how flexible you want the application to be.

Comment: Can you give an example of what are you trying to say? I mean a code. I can't catch up of what your saying, i'm just new to web developement. Just a simple detailed code, All i know is just basic MVC and basic JSP , javascript

Comment: It depends on the MVC that you're using. Some MVCs will convert objects to a `JSON` string automatically and some will not. If your MVC framework doesn't, I would suggest looking `GSON` (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). After you determine whether or not your framework can return a `JSON` object, the implementation should be relatively straight forward (either you create a method that returns the object or you create a method that writes the `JSON` to the response).